# Trying to delete files from remote server : encountering he error : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, ftp

I am using this code to delete files

```
    Protected Sub DeleteFTP(strFTPFilePath As String, strUserName As String, strPassword As String)

    Dim requestFileDelete As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strFTPFilePath)
    requestFileDelete.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword)
    requestFileDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

    Dim responseFileDelete As HttpWebResponse = requestFileDelete.GetResponse()


     End Sub
```

This line : 
`Dim responseFileDelete As HttpWebResponse = requestFileDelete.GetResponse()`
generating the error .

Answer (score 0):

Cool . .. I  got the solution . 
Replace the HttpWebRequest with Ftp